# c# razor error: The name 'i' does not exist in this current context

Tags: c#

I am pulling a list of data from the web and placing my array into my drop down menu. I am using razor script and I get the following error on LINE 4:

```
The name 'i' does not exist in this current context
```

Here is my code:

```
var select = document.getElementById('propertyMenu');
            for (var i = 0; i < @Model.propertiesArray.Length; i++)
            {
                var property = "@Model.propertiesArray[i]"
                var element = document.createElement('option');
                element.textContent = property;
                element.value = property;
            }
```

Now I know that using the '@' symbol allows you to access classes from my models within my javascript via C#. So my guess is that the Javascript variable 'i' won't be accessible unless I give it some sort of directive.

How do I access my int count 'i' within the context?

EDIT:

I answered my own question.

Comment: That's fundamentally impossible.  You need to understand the difference between _client-side_ code and _server-side_ code.

Comment: `Now I know that using the '@' symbol allows you to access classes from my models within my javascript` - no, this does not happen. You can generate javascript and use `@` in the process, but you can't refer to `@` at javascript's runtime.

Comment: @SLaks, you couldn't be more correct. I figured it out and posted my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var propertiesArray = new Array();
@foreach (var props in Model.propertiesArray)
{
    @:propertiesArray.push("@props");
}

var select = document.getElementById("propertyMenu");
for (var i = 0; i < propertiesArray.length; i++)
   {
       var property = propertiesArray[i]; 
       var element = document.createElement('option');
       element.textContent = property;
       element.value = property;
       select.appendChild(element);
   }
```

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, dump the array as a JSON literal and consume it in pure Javascript.

Comment: @SLaks, I edited my answer. Yeah, this works a lot better. Are there any performance related reasons for doing it this way? Thanks again.

Comment: You have an XSS hole. Use a JSON serializer to dump the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

can not tell if your code is C# or JS.

You may have to do it this way

```
var select = document.getElementById('propertyMenu');
        for (var i = 0; i < @Model.propertiesArray.Length; i++)
        {
            var property = @Model.propertiesArray[i].toString();
            var element = document.createElement('option');
            element.textContent = property;
            element.value = property;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

because you are using in Javascript codes. You can try this.

```
@{
   string values = "";
   for(int i=0;i<Model.propertiesArray.Length;i++)
      values += Model.propertiesArray[i].ToString()+(i!=Model.propertiesArray.Lenght-1)?",":"";
 }

<script>
var value = '@values';
var values = value.split(',');
var select = document.getElementById('propertyMenu');
    for (var i = 0; i < values .length; i++)
    {
        var property = values[i];
        var element = document.createElement('option');
        element.textContent = property;
        element.value = property;
    }
</script>
```

I wrote Stackoverflow editor.